# How many equations of this inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

What is the other equation for this inequality?

$|2x - 7| \ge 1$

Is it $|2x - 7| \ge -1$

or $|2x - 7| \le -1$

Comment: It's hard to understand your question.

Comment: Ok. an inequality has 2 equations yes? I don't know the other oen for mine. eg |2x| = 5 has 2 equations such as |2x| = -5, or |2x| = 5. what about |2x - 7| >= 1

Comment: What is meant by $|2x|=-5$ I do not understand;)

Comment: Hi, |2x| = -5 is part of |2x| = 5 because it has 2 equations

Comment: The second option without the `||`.

Answer (score 4):

$$|2x-7|\geq 1 \implies -(2x- 7)\geq 1 \text{ or } (2x - 7) \geq 1$$

So the two corresponding inequalities to the given inequality are

$$-(2x- 7)\geq 1 \iff 2x - 7 \leq -1\iff 2x \leq 6 \iff x \leq 3$$

OR

$$2x-7 \geq 1 \iff 2x \geq 8 \iff x \geq 4$$

So the solutions are given by all $x$ in $(-\infty, 3] \cup [4, \infty)$.

Comment: So basically to find out the other, reverse ALL signs?

Comment: We use the definition of $$|x| = \begin{cases} x & x > 0\\ -x& x< 0\end{cases}$$ And we also use the fact that multiplying each side of an inequality by a negative quantity changes the direction of the inequality.